# Selecting specific attributes in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

From the Hash below titled 'mambu_repayments' I am trying to iterate over it and only select the repayments that have a state value of anything but GRACE. I run the code and yet everything remains the same all fields are appearing on my view with GRACE and other states

```
for repayment in mambu_repayments.select {[:state] != 'GRACE'} do
// some code here
end
```

Any help would be great, my syntax needs tweaking..

Comment: if you know the key for the symbol that you want to remove you can use except , here is the reference https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except

Comment: So, I'm trying to remove anything from the hash? I just dont want to display certain objects in the hash that have the key 'state' that has a value of GRACE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
for repayment in mambu_repayments.select {|o| o[:state] != 'GRACE'} do
  // some code here
end
```

Comment: I will try this code I had something similar that had o.[:state]

Comment: @Llanod11 look at my answer. In ruby we don't use `for`, it is bad practice

Comment: I agree with @PrzemekMroczek. I haven't really seen `for` used in any Ruby application. That doesn't mean it should never be used, but unless you have a good reason I would use `each`. Here's a link to a ruby style guide which gives a better answer: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-for-loops

Answer (score 1):

'for' are ugly in oriented object language, it do the trick with one more line but consume less memory

```
mambu_repayments.each do |mambu_repayment|
  # Skip GRACE
  next if mambu_repayment[:state] == 'GRACE'

  # Your view code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off Erez Rabih's answer.. the below worked..

```
for repayment in mambu_repayments.select  {|s| s["state"] != 'GRACE'} do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am guessing you are using some kind of collection for payments. This is my answer and you could easily check it from irb.

```
mambu_repayments = [ { name: 'awesome', state: 'DIFFERENT'}, { name: 'great', state: 'GRACE'} ]

mambu_repayments.select { |payment| payment[:state] != 'GRACE' }.each do |payment|
  puts payment
end
```